# Associate Google accounts with existing Windows profiles

Tags: powershell, registry, credentials, profile

We are looking to setup [Google Credential Provider for Windows](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9250996?hl=en) (GCPW) as we are mostly Google in our environment. After installing the application if someone signs in a new profile is created. [To Associate Google accounts with existing Windows profiles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9796679?hl=en&ref_topic=9539498) a registry key must be made with the users SID and an email value of the user.

The issue I am having is creating the email value with the profile name for each users SID. You will see I am trying to get the username from "ProfileImagePath" take out the path and keep the profile name. Then add that to the email value for each matching SID key that is created for each user that has signed into the machine previously.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Error:**

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'ProfileImagePath'.
At C:\Temp\Untitled3.ps1:18 char:98
+ ... -Name 'email' -Value $($user.ProfileImagePath()+"@domain.org")
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ProfileImagePath:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\Google\GCPW\Users\@{PSChildName=S-1-5-21-<OMITTED>; ProfileImagePath=<OMITTED>}.PSChildName' because it does not exist.
At C:\Temp\Untitled3.ps1:18 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Google\GCPW\Users\$user.PSChild ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software\...ia}.PSChildName:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

**Code:**

```
#### Export SID and profile path (for username) ####
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-*'
$getInfo = Get-ItemProperty -Path $path | Select-Object -Property PSChildName, ProfileImagePath
$export = $getInfo | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\SID1.csv -NoTypeInformation

#### Remove "C:\Users\" in Export ####
$mod = Get-Content C:\Temp\SID1.csv
$mod | ForEach-Object { $_-replace 'C:\\Users\\', ""} | Set-Content "C:\Temp\SID1.csv"

#### Import the Export ####
$info = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\SID1.csv

#### Create SID key. Then add email value in SID key of user. ####
ForEach ($user in $info) {

New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Google\GCPW\Users -Name $user.PSChildName -Force

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Google\GCPW\Users\$user.PSChildName -Name 'email' -Value $($user.ProfileImagePath()+"@domain.org")

}
```

Comment: why are you calling a method? that is almost certainly just a _property_ ... so get rid of the `()` that makes it into a method call. [*grin*]

Comment: That corrected the method error. Thank you so much! Now I need to fix the Set-ItemProperty error. Not sure why it cannot find the path even though it is created.

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// for the path error ... [1] check permissions. [2] see how deep you can go down the tree in PoSh to determine where the error happens.

Comment: Solved! Just needed to make `$user.PSChildName` a variable to call for the set item. Thank you again so much for your help!

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]